# how to change the input field according the string count

Tags: jquery, mask

I have a fax number column and I want to auto adjust to particular format. I am using the jQuery mask input plugin.

If the user enters 10 digits it should be formatted like this: `545.555.4546`.

If the user enters 11 digits it should be formatted like this: `1 545.555.4546`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

`<input id="tax1" type="text">`

JS:

```
var options =  {onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options){
var masks = ['000.000.00000', '0  000.000.0000'];      
    if(cep.length === 13){
        mask = masks[1];        
    }
    if(cep.length <= 12 || cep.length === 14){
        mask = masks[0];        
    }       
    $('#tax1').mask(mask, options);
}};

$('#tax1').mask('000.000.00000', options);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sidanmor/swhnax2u/1/)

Comment: what should i do if i enter 11 digts

Comment: Do you want it to be dynamic? if the user type more than 10 digits then the format changed it self?

Comment: Yeah. format should change based  on the input length @idan mor

Comment: Is 11 the maximum number of digits that the user can type?

Comment: Yes maximum length is 11 digits

Comment: Try this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sidanmor/15q5gunv/7/)

And this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sidanmor/15q5gunv/6/)

Not what you really want but maybe it will help, I will try to find the solution letter... Please read this, maybe it will help you...

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/